# MapBox MBTiles Layers issue

Tags: ios, sqlite, mkmapview

I am very new to MapBox, I am able to retrieve values from MBTile sqlite file using Sqlite manager,  Where as in the Mapbox methods below

```
- (void)singleTapOnMap:(RMMapView *)mapVi at:(CGPoint)point1 {
   [mapVi removeAllAnnotations];

   RMMapboxSource *source = (RMMapboxSource *)mapVi.tileSource;

   if ([source conformsToProtocol:@protocol(RMInteractiveSource)] && [source supportsInteractivity])
   {
       NSLog(@"formetted1 op=%@ and 2=%@",formattedOutput,formattedOutput2);

       if (formattedOutput && [formattedOutput length])
       {            
           [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
       }        
       NSLog(@"You tapped at %f, %f", [mapVi pixelToCoordinate:point1].latitude, [mapVi pixelToCoordinate:point1].longitude);     
   }
}
```

here I get the Latitude and longitude of clicking point but I need some more to get the data from database,

How can I do that. Please Help me

&Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following formula to convert latitude and longitude to Tile Row/Column.

Use following link for formula http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers

Then map it with the help of SQLlite.